# Writing to a file in Angular 6

Tags: angular, file

I am trying to implement something like "you are visitor number n" in my angular 6 app. I am not using a database, so the best thing is to store the number in a file in the assets folder say, then read the number off of it, update and store the incremented number.

Reading is easy, as in:

```
this.http.get("/assets/visits").subscribe(vn => {
  this.visitNums = +vn + 1;
});
```

But I am having a problem writing to the file. I tried:

```
fs.writeFile("/assets/visits, 'whatever',
             err => console.log(err));
```

But I get a "fs module not found" even with:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

And also, doing a:

```
declare const fs: any;
```

given "fs is not defined" on that `fs.writeFile` line.

So, is there a way to write to a file from within an Angular 6 app?

Comment: As @abdullahkady mentioned, this is not possible. Consider instead using a cloud "database" such as Firebase to store this value. Firebase and Angular work well together. check out the tutorial here: https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-firebase-typescript-step-by-step-tutorial-2ef887fc7d71

Comment: I know how to do it with databases with Mongo or Firebase being best options. But, for just a single number to store and fetch between reads, it's not worth it as I am also not paying anything now.

Comment: I didn't think either database required paying anything?

Comment: Thought they do! Right now I am deploying an app on heroku for free. Setting up a database connection with some provider should, although maybe not for something insignificant like for just visits number. Still, I would like to do it with files if possible.

Comment: Apparently there is a free level: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible at all, even as a concept.
The "assets" folder resides on your own server, you can't let a client write to it simply when visiting from another machine, which means he will have no access to your file system (hence the "fs", which is a node.js module by the way, meaning it's code won't be present in the browser).

Comment: Fine, how? And frankly I don't know why the two upvotes. I asked: is there a way? And, I gave the ways I used that didn't solve my problem, and they did involve the `fs` being mentioned here.

Comment: No way to achieve that purely on the client end of the application, you will have to make use of any server storage.
As @Deborahk mentioned, firebase is one of the easiest services that you can use for your case

Comment: Never meant client end here, the question is asking for if a value can be stored and manipulated in files instead of databases.

Comment: You know what, you are "maybe" right. When fasting, you start missing some important articles. I read your "not possible at all" as "very possible of course"! How? I have no idea. Now I get what you said from what DeborahK is saying. Forgive my misread and my wondering why the two upvotes. +1 and a Right from me.